# Add event listener not attaching event to element

Tags: javascript

I have this code which has a createDom function which takes a dom element object and its parent as argument and creates the dom element.
It creates the elements but problem is in the add event listener part.

```
(function()

{

    var createDom=function(obj,parent)

    {

        var i=2,element,a,number,n,j,type;
        element=document.createElement(obj.tag);
        for(i=1;i<Object.keys(obj).length;i++)
        {
            a=Object.keys(obj)[i];  //Get Key Name
            type=typeof(obj[a]);


            if(type!='object')
            element[a]=obj[a];          

            if(a=='events')
            {
                for(k in obj[a])    
                {

                    element.addEventListener(k,obj[a][k]);
                }   
            }

        }
        parent.appendChild(element);


    }



    function removeNode(e)
    {
        alert('ss');
    }

    var c=  {
            tag:'input',
            type:'radio',
            name:'options',
            events:{
                            "click":"removeNode"
                        },
                    }
    createDom(c,document.body);

})();
```

Why the event listener is not attaching event to the radio button?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Can you please format the code in your question to make it readable.  Messed up indentation, tons of blank lines, etc...

Comment: Ideally provide a JSFiddle or JSBin etc

Comment: `for(i=1;i<Object.keys(obj).length;i++)`…? Use a `for in` or `forEach` instead.

Comment: i have to start the loop from the second attribute of the object so i used a for loop @minitech

Comment: @RanojitBanerjee - are you under the impression that `Object.keys()` produces a specific order of those keys such that one specific key will always be first in the returned array?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(function()
{
        var createDom=function(obj, parent)
        {
                var i=2, element, a, number, n, j, type;
                element=document.createElement(obj.tag);
                for(i=1; i < Object.keys(obj).length; i++)
                {
                        a=Object.keys(obj)[i];  //Get Key Name
                        type= typeof(obj[a]);
                        if(type != 'object')
                        {
                                element[a]=obj[a];
                        }
                        if(a == 'events')
                        {
                                for(var k in obj[a])
                                {
                                        console.log(obj[a][k]);
                                        element.addEventListener(k, obj[a][k]);
                                }
                        }
                }
                parent.appendChild(element);
        };
        var c={
                tag   : 'input',
                type  : 'radio',
                name  : 'options',
                events: {
                        "click": function()
                        {
                                alert();
                        }
                }
        };
        createDom(c, document.body);
})();
```

Second argument of eventListener has to be **function expression**..You had provided string..